# Closed form expression for discrete-time sum of a cosinusoid

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometric-series, discrete-time

I'm facing a problem in digital signal processing and am wondering if there is a closed form expression for the sum

$$Y[n] = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos(\frac{2\pi k}{f}),$$

where $n$ < $f$.

In case I haven't worded my question correctly, I'd like to be able to calculate $Y[n]$ with only $n$ and $f$ and no discrete sum. Intuitively, I think it should be a sinusoid and if I plot y[n] it seems that this is true, however I haven't found a way to simplify the sum of cosinusoids into this closed form.

Comment: $cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$ and you have two geometric sums.

Comment: $Y_f(n)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \cos\left(\frac{2 \pi k}{f}\right)=\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{f}\right)\, \sin\left(\frac{n \pi}{f}\right)\, \cos\left(\frac{(n-1) \pi}{f}\right)$

Comment: @StevenClark, thanks yes that's the solution I was looking for. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept. At least I'm new to stack exchange so I think that's how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematica and [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5BCos%5B%282%20Pi%20k%29%2Ff%5D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2Cn-1%7D%5D) give the following result.

$$Y_f(n)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \cos\left(\frac{2 \pi k}{f}\right)=\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{f}\right)\, \sin\left(\frac{n \pi}{f}\right)\, \cos\left(\frac{(n-1) \pi}{f}\right)$$